# Polymer theme not showing when using together Angular 2 without Chrome

Tags: css, typescript, angular, material-design, polymer-1.0

I'm developing a webapp using Angular 2 and Polymer, since Material design support for Angular 2 is very poor.

The problem here is that when I run the application in Firefox, IE or Edge the application is shown without styles. When I run it in chrome it runs with styles.

Why is it happening and how could I solve this?

Edit:
I inspected the elements in Chrome and Firefox and the elementos  dom seems different.

Comment: Are you loading webcomponents polyfills?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192424/styling-polymer-element-in-angular2/37193613#37193613, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779175/polymer-elements-within-angular-2-component/34782260#34782260, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490068/how-to-use-css-mixins-with-angular-2-dart-and-polymer/37495705#37495705, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864501/using-paper-datatable-in-angular2/36864636#36864636

Comment: Shadow dom is enabled with dom: 'shadow'. How could I enable polyfills?

Comment: Like shown in https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings
The `webcomponents-lite.js` needs to be before the script that enables shadow DOM and both must come before any element import.

Comment: It is there. Should works correctly.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker? Hard to discuss imaginary code ;-)

Comment: Without bower and npm dependencies installed for size reasons: http://www.filedropper.com/ang2-cad-clientes

Comment: npm start on the root to run.